# completely block title bar from sliding down android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, customization

with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"`
app hides the title bar and using

```
  WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
customViewGroup view = new customViewGroup(this);

    manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
```

I can override the notification tray.
But i want to remove complete title bar + notification bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by making some funny changes in systemUI apps layout file "super_status_bar.xml"

```
 <include layout="@layout/status_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    />
 <com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PanelHolder
    android:id="@+id/panel_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    >
```

The panel holder is for notification tray

i know this is a bad trick but it worked :)